# Error with Firebase Realtime Database Content Security Policy - script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, content-security-policy

I have a chrome extension that uses firebase realtime database and authentication. In the chrome extension, a user has multiple profiles, where these profiles are stored in the realtime database. I am getting an issue with retrieving the profiles under a users account. I am seeing this error in my console randomly (it will work just fine at first, and after awhile stop working), and I have to unload and reload the chrome extension for it to work again.

I get the following error:

```
Refused to load the script '(firebase link)' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I believe that the issue is stemming from my manifest.json? Here is my manifest.json file

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "dummy text",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "dummy text",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "service-worker":"firebase.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "webRequest",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [[website], [website], "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/*"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"],
            "css": ["styles.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Would really appreciate any help, I’ve been stuck on this for awhile. Thank you so much!